# How can I instantiate optimised modules in requirejs outside of the optimised file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

In my require.config I create shorthands for a couple of paths that I use regularly:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        text: 'components/requirejs-text/text',
        url: 'config/url',
        List: 'modules/List/main'
        ...
```

Then on the individual pages (in separate script files), I instantiate  a module like this:

```
require(['List'], function(List){ new List; });
```

My plan was to optimise all files into one file, require that and instantiate a module as in my example, but since the paths of require.config aren't really relevant anymore (Because I now only have main.build.js) **how can I instantiate my modules**?

**UPDATE: Let me rephrase:**

I'm trying to instantiate a module outside of the optimised build script, how do I do that?

Comment: The paths are treated as the module names, and those module names are kept when the file is merged. Your modules are instantiated when other code `require`s them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you want to include the `List` module just create a new paths configuration which points to the optimized file.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'List': 'js/myApp' 
    }
});
require(['List'], function(List) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This should load js/myApp.js and return the List module as long as define('List', ...) exists within that file.

Comment: Oh. Thank you, that's actually the answer I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Move your config into a separate location (either inline in the head, or in a JS file) that is after the `require.js` library. Now you can load any modules in the future and they will all be able to read the config regardless of which ones are loaded first.

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to incur requests for modules that are already loaded in main-built.js

Comment: If you're trying to request modules inside the built file from another separate module then you're likely to have problems with race conditions. A common scenario is having jQuery in the build file and then needing it again in a separate one. If the main file takes longer to load then you'll have failures. In that scenario I create a built file of my common libraries (jQuery, plugins etc). Loading 3-4 built files async is still a performance benefit in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

i think, we have one file called appInit.js, which do instantiate our application, so after that all other modules should instantiate on requirement, and also its not good practice to instantiate modules from every module.js,

consider single instance of Application and all other instance should relate to this application as components, services etc.,

every developer has his own coding style, choose what you are comfortable with..

if you are worrying about paths of modules, after building then don't worry paths are just the name of module, and it should work, but dynamically loaded or created modules won't work any more.

Comment: but how do I refer to a particular Module outside of the optimised main.build.js ?

Comment: i can't understand? but remember
 we don't need to change our code on build, it will be done automatically for you.

require('mod',function(Mod){
// do
});

Comment: even if this is outside the optimised file in a separate script tag?

Comment: no that will not work, bcoz thats not included in build time, and that is equal to dynamcally created modules. you have to specify paths for them,

Comment: It doesn't tell me how I can use one of the modules inside the buildscript outside of it...